# Loading a pandas dataframe with tensorflow and making predictions with a single instance

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am having trouble understanding building a tensorflow model and preprocessing a pandas Dataframe.

Ive been following this documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe

First question:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))
train_dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(df)).batch(1)

def get_compiled_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])
```

Since the heart disease dataframe has 13 features, why did the documentation only initate the first Dense layer with only 10 units? Why didn't it look something like this?

```
def get_compiled_model():
      model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(13,),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
      ])
```

In the docs, it starts with a Dense layer of 10 units, but there are 13 features, I dont understand how this works.

Last question:

After Ive trained the model

```
model = get_compiled_model()
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=15)
```

How do I make predictions with a single or multiple instance/instances of training data using the model.predict()?

Do I have to convert the instance to a tensor first before passing it into the model.predict method?
i.e

model.predict(`tensor(instance)`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create a model.

1. model.build()
2. model.fit() with some data
3. Specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

Even if you don't specify the input layer, when you fit the data, it will automatically adjust the input size.

The model.predict() should be given input similar to the training data. It can be single or multiple (batches) inputs.